# Firebase API initialization failure.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated the FCM Database in my Android project. I used it for chat application. Now I need to implement the cloud message(Push notification) using FireBase. After I implement the FCM, I got an error-

> **Firebase API initialization failure. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**

I am sending the gradle script please have a look.

Module :app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.swatin.groupchatapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
             }
           }
 }
 repositories {
 mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile project(':libbambuser-0.9.12')
compile 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:1.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0-rc1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
} 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (Project: ProjectName)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: When I changed classpath `'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'` to latest `4.2.0` error is gone(Flutter user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, you need to add the following line of code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

As the last line in your `build.gradle (Project: ProjectName)` file.

And if you are using also authentication, please also this line of code:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
```

I also strongly recommend you to use the latest versions for your Firebase dependencies. The latest version is now: `11.8.0`.

The last version for Google Play Services is:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Comment: Sorry is it Project: ProjectName or Module :app ?

Comment: I change the class path. classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' but still same error.

Comment: Be sure to have the latest and the same versions to all  of your dependencies. See also Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) compatibilities.

Comment: Yes, update all your depenedencies to the last version.

Comment: Hi can you suggest any solution about "Push notification though app is not oppen? Like gmail or Whatsapp"

Comment: I don't understand you. Have updated the dependencies to the last version? Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, I can suugest you see my: [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee). It contains also how to send push notifications.

Comment: Yes I made changes in project Gradle:
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
Error gone

But please suggest some push notification abut app is not open even not in foreground and background.